# Naughty backOffIfDiskSpoolFull

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, ehcache

When my Spring Boot + Data JPA 1.5 application is put under heavy load, after a while (a couple of minutes in this case), the repository save halts for 20-30 seconds because [EhCache "backs-off" by putting the thread to sleep](https://github.com/svn2github/ehcache/blob/master/tags/ehcache-core-2.0.0/src/main/java/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.java#L1245) because its disk spool is full:

```
"pool-2-thread-1" sleeping[0x00007fc1a95ae000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep
    at ehcache.Cache.backOffIfDiskSpoolFull
    at ehcache.Cache.putInternal
    at ehcache.Cache.put
    at ehcache.Cache.put
    ... many Hibernate, Spring, Sun frames
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.save
```

(trimmed `net.sf.` from ehcache for clarity)

As a result, performance plummets and this makes me sad.

I have **not** defined an `ehcache.xml`; I have only added the `hibernate-ehcache` dependency and enabled caching via `@EnableCaching` annotation. Despite not having provided `ehcache.xml` Hibernate is still clearly using Ehcache as the stacktrace shows above.

I'd like to reconfigure EhCache to not use [`DiskStore`](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/get-started/storage-options.html) but do all the other magic that it's doing now (via Spring Boot, Spring Data, Hibernate, etc.). To avoid trying to re-creating the effective/magical `ehcache.xml` that apparently is present now, is there an EhCache bean where I can just disable persistence, or something equivalently surgical? Alternatively, is there someway that I can print the effective Ehcache configuration?

Comment: I'm not familar enough with EhCache but I would think it possible to create the cache's via java configuration and wire up the cache manager yourself. http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/configuration.html#introduction but personally a little XML is cleaner to maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.5 with Spring Data JPA uses Hibernate 5.0.12.Final; and, Hibernate 5.0.12.Final uses [Ehcache 2.4.3](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/EhcacheUserGuide-2.4.pdf) internally. To disable disk-writes, you will need to disable disk in the default cache configuration which Hibernate uses, and also disable disk use in any application defined caches, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>
  <defaultCache
      maxElementsInMemory="10000"
      eternal="false"
      timeToIdleSeconds="120"
      timeToLiveSeconds="120"
      overflowToDisk="false"
      maxElementsOnDisk="0"
      diskPersistent="false"
      diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
      memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
      />

  <cache name="my-cache-1" />
  ...
  <cache name="my-cache-n" />
</ehcache>
```

Answer (score 2):

The disk store is defined in the Ehcache configuration. Which is in the `ehcache.xml`.

So removing the disk store from the `ehcache.xml` is kinda the way to go.

From your added explanation: Hibernate tries to be nice with you and creates caches with default parameters. But it's a really bad idea to use these parameters.

You need to put some thoughts into your caching configuration.

- How many elements should it hold?
- Should they expire?
- Do I need disk? (most of the time the answer is indeed "no" here)

If you don't do it, you will end up with stale data or `OutOfMemoryError`s.

So I highly recommend that you use your own well-thought `ehcache.xml` instead of Hibernate magic.

Comment: Thanks, @Henri -- is there some way to show the effective configuration so I don't lose the magic...?

Comment: Not getting you. What magic? And the effective configuration should be the `ehcache.xml` one unless you are adding new caches are runtime.

Comment: I've added some clarifications to better describe my confusion, and what I mean by "magic"; see above.